# If vector $y_1 = (1,2,3)$ and $y_2 = (4,5,6)$, how to calculate orthogonal projector $\prod\{y_1\}$ onto subspace spaned by the vectors $y_1,y_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

If I have a vector $y_1 = (1,2,3)$ and  $y_2 = (4,5,6)$, how to calculate $\prod\{y_{1}\}$ and $\prod\{(y_{i})_{1\leq i \leq2}\}$ according to the definition below?

> denote $\Pi \{ y_1,...,y_k\}$ the orthogonal projector onto the
>   subspace spanned by the vectors $y_1,...,y_k$. The projector is a $T \times T$ matrix, where $T$ is the length of these vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a matrix $A$, the orthogonal projector $P$ onto the span of the columns of $A$ is given by,
$$ P = A(A^*A)^{-1}A^*$$

Therefore, in your notation,
$$ \prod\{y_1\} = \left[\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\3\end{array}\right] \left( \left[\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\3\end{array}\right]^*\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\3\end{array}\right]\right)^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\3\end{array}\right]^* = \frac{1}{14}\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 2 & 4 & 6 \\
 3 & 6 & 9 \\
\end{array}
\right]$$
and
$$ \prod\{y_1,y_2\} = \left[\begin{array}{c}1&4\\2&5\\3&6\end{array}\right] \left( \left[\begin{array}{c}1&4\\2&5\\3&6\end{array}\right]^*\left[\begin{array}{c}1&4\\2&5\\3&6\end{array}\right]\right)^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{c}1&4\\2&5\\3&6\end{array}\right]^* = \frac{1}{6}\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 5 & 2 & -1 \\
 2 & 2 & 2 \\
 -1 & 2 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right] $$

Comment: May I ask a little more if I have another set of vectors $n_1,n_2$ - For $\prod \{ (y_i)_{1\leq i \leq 2}, (n_i)_{1\leq i \leq 2} \}$, is it correct to calculate $\prod \{ y_1,y_2 \}$ and $\prod \{ n_1,n_2 \}$ separately first, then calculate projection from 2 matrices like $\prod \{\prod \{ y_1,y_2 \},\prod \{ n_1,n_2 \}\}$?

Comment: There isn't really any difference between the $n$ and $y$ vectors other than labeling, so you can just use the method in the top level answer.